# MySQL user per database performance implications?

Tags: mysql

There is a PHP application that uses only one MySQL username. And there are several databases in the MySQL server. Each database is used by a different company. Should I keep "one MySQL" for the entire system or should I switch to "user per database"? Will I have performance increase if I switch to "user per database"?

Comment: This should be a security concern, not a performance concern. Do the companies have direct access to the database, or is everything going through APIs/software?

Comment: @Phil, they don't have database access.

Comment: @ilhan I would still recommend setting up seperate users. It doesn't require much work and can be beneficial

Comment: It sounds like `USE company_db` is your level of security.

Answer (score 2):

Using different users will not reduce or increase the performance. It is clearly a security issue.

Usually you don't want users from company A to be able to access company B data.

I would recommend to create separate users for each application and grant them only the necessary permissions.

If you run the application using a user with admin rights you risk a lot when the application gets compromised.

Comment: However, it sounds like there is _one_ application that works for _all_ databases (ie, companies).